# Next button in Java swing for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing

My code for next button to display the next row of my database doesn't display the next row instead it immediately display the last row of my database.

```
JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/anonymization", "root", "password");
                String examNames = textExamName.getText();
                String selectTable = "Select * FROM " +examNames+"";
                Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet examresults = statement.executeQuery(selectTable);
                if(examresults.next()){
                    String number = examresults.getString("number");
                    String content = examresults.getString("content");
                    String choiceA = examresults.getString("choiceA");
                    String choiceB = examresults.getString("choiceB");
                    String choiceC = examresults.getString("choiceC");
                    String choiceD = examresults.getString("choiceD");
                    textNumber.setText(number);
                    textAreaQuestion.setText(content);
                    textAreaA.setText(choiceA);
                    textAreaB.setText(choiceB);
                    textAreaC.setText(choiceC);
                    textAreaD.setText(choiceD);
                }
                else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "last record");
                    }


            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnSubmit.setBounds(309, 483, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnSubmit);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [asl] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: my apologies. what I mean is when I clicked my "next" button that should display the next record(row) from my database in mySQL, it immediately display the last record. from record 1 to record 5(last). it skips 2,3,4 record. I need help to display the 2nd, 3rd and 4th before the last record.

Comment: Without a suitable `WHERE` clause, your query will return an arbitrary row; it is also vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @trashgod - thanks for your input. I tried editing my queries to this, but it's only stays at first record. 
**String examNumber = textNumber.getText();                                              String selectTable = "Select * FROM " +examNames+" WHERE number = "+examNumber+"";**